# Rail unable to autoload controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm getting the error below when trying create a new user_subscription in my rails application.

Unable to autoload constant UserSubscriptionsController, expected /Users/antarrbyrd/dev/rail-app/app/controllers/user_subscriptions_controller.rb to define it

## app/controllers/user_subscriptions_controller.b

```
class UserSubsciptionController < ApplicationController
  def create
    user_id = params[:user_id]
    app_id = params[:app_id]
    UserSubsciption.find_or_create_by(user_id: user_id, app_id: app_id)
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

## config/routes.rb

```
  get 'user_subcriptions/create/:user_id/:app_id', to: 'user_subscriptions#create', as: 'create_subscription'
```

## app/models/user_subscription.rb

```
class UserSubscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :app
end
```

## app/view/apps/_full.html.erb

```
<h5>
  <%= link_to 'Watch this app', create_subscription_path(session[:user_id], app.id) %>
</h5>
```

## local variable

Local Variables

```
from_mod  Object
const_name  :UserSubscriptionsController
qualified_name  "UserSubscriptionsController"
path_suffix "user_subscriptions_controller"
file_path "/Users/antarrbyrd/dev/.../app/controllers/user_subscriptions_controller.rb"
expanded "/Users/antarrbyrd/dev/.../app/controllers/user_subscriptions_controller"
mod  nil
parent  nil
e nil
```

Comment: Look at the name of the controller it is trying to load, and the name of controller class that you have, and you will see the error. :)

Comment: ^ You mispelled Subsc**r**iptionController in your class definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the file app/controllers/user_subscriptions_controller.b rename the class `UserSubscriptionsController` to `UserSubsciptionsController`

Comment: It now throws the error `raise "Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant #{qualified_name}"`

Comment: It was actually missing an r as well `UserSubscriptionsController`